# open file without mouse, intellij idea 8.1

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there some easy way to open a file (that is not in the project) with the keyboard only?

Answer (score 7):

I'm on 6 rather than 8.1, but the following may hold.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> works for files in the project. For files outside the project there is no default Keymap. You can set one yourself though.

Go to Preferences - Keymap-Main menu-File-Open File... and set it to any keystroke you want.

I've just tried the open dialog using keyboard only, and it's not too bad, you just have to know to stay in the filename box. So if you wanted /home/user then type /home/user and hit return, it will change you to that directory. Not as good as the nice completion in crtl-shift-N, but not unusable.

Comment: with Ctrl-Shift-N i cant open say /home/user/foo.txt just by writing it.. Theres a checkbox for 'include non-project files', but it seems to be working in mysteries ways..

Comment: thx, I bound the open file dialog to ctrl-shift-o, but the dialog is just terrible to navigate with a keyboard.. so its not really a solution :(

Comment: Sorry, you've stumped me then. I'm guessing it's not possible then - I'd submit a bug-report/feature request to IntelliJ, they've been helpful to me in the past

Comment: just added suggestion on using dialog box

Comment: the dialog box suggestions are not valid on my system, I'm afraid. It really is broken when using the keyboard (linux / idea 8.1)